# Can we move data (repository) from CVS 1.10.10 to new version cvs 1.11.23?

Tags: windows-xp, cvs

I am using CVS version 1.10.10 and now i want to use new version available in market i.e cvs 1.11.23. Is it possible without affecting data or is it working fine in newer version?